# Selenium 2 gettext() without getting those from subnode

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, gettext

I have a web page that has the following html code:

```
....
<div class="some_class">Text I want 
   <span class="another_class">Text I don't want</span>
   ....more junk...
   ....a lot more junk....
</div>
```

I tried to call getText(), which gives me all the text within the div which contains a lot of other text that I don't want. My question is: how can I get ONLY the text I want without resort to some kind of parsing or extracting substring etc?

Thank you!

Comment: Not hat I can think of, but I can help you figure an acceptably reliable way to do it with parsing/substringing if you change your mind.

Comment: I am doing it with substring for now: finding the index of the text by class name "another_class" and sub-string 0 to that index.

Comment: And is that working for you?

Comment: @user1596683 have you tried my solution? It should work well for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this with JavaScript. If your webDriver (like Firefox, Chrome, ...) supports that, you can do it like this:

```
public class Main
{

    //@formatter:off
    final static String JS_SCRIPT_GET_TEXT  = "var element = arguments[0];                                      " +
                                              "var text = '';                                                   " + 
                                              "for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++)              " + 
                                              " if (element.childNodes[i].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)          " + 
                                              " {                                                               " + 
                                              "   text += element.childNodes[i].textContent + ' ';              " +
                                              " }                                                               " + 
                                              "return text;                                                     ";
    //@formatter:on

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML");

        final List<WebElement> findElementsByCssSelector = driver.findElementsByCssSelector("#mw-content-text div");

        final WebElement webElement = findElementsByCssSelector.get(0);

        final String extractInnerText = extractInnerText(webElement, driver);

        System.out.println("---------------------");
        System.out.println("Seleniums .getText():\n" + webElement.getText());

        System.out.println("\n\n---------------------");
        System.out.println("Just the node text:\n" + extractInnerText);

    }

    public static String extractInnerText(final WebElement webElement, final WebDriver webDriver)
    {
        final JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;

        String webElementText = (String) javascriptExecutor.executeScript(JS_SCRIPT_GET_TEXT, webElement);
        webElementText = webElementText.trim();

        return webElementText;
    }
}
```

For this example Html:

```
<div class="dablink">
    For the use of HTML on Wikipedia, see
    <a href="/wiki/Help:HTML_in_wikitext" title="Help:HTML in wikitext">Help:HTML in wikitext</a>
    .
</div>
```

It will print you:

```
---------------------
Seleniums .getText():
For the use of HTML on Wikipedia, see Help:HTML in wikitext.


---------------------
Just the node text:
For the use of HTML on Wikipedia, see  .
```

I think thats what you need. You can apply the `extractInnerText(..)` method to every webelement.